# How to remove the 0s in the id_sum column by a sequence from 1 to n in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, data-transform, partition-by

I have the following pyspark dataframe **df_model**:

| id_client | id_sku |
| --- | --- |
| 1111 | 4444 |
| 1111 | 4444 |
| 2222 | 6666 |
| 2222 | 6666 |
| 3333 | 777 |

And i use this code to generate the column id_frecuence:

```
t = df_model.collect()[0][0]
w = Window.partitionBy('id_client').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding,0).orderBy('col')
df =df_model.withColumn('id_sum',
 f.sum(f.when(f.col('id_client') !=t  , 1)
 .otherwise(0))
 .over(w))
```

**and my output is:**

| id_client | id_sku | id_sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 4444 | 0 |
| 1111 | 4444 | 0 |
| 2222 | 6666 | 1 |
| 2222 | 6666 | 2 |
| 3333 | 777 | 1 |

But i want to obtain the follow result:

| id_client | id_sku | id_sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 4444 | 1 |
| 1111 | 4444 | 2 |
| 2222 | 6666 | 1 |
| 2222 | 6666 | 2 |
| 3333 | 777 | 1 |

My question is whats wrong with the code.

Actually I'm trying to use a Windowfunction and my code is like this:

```
t = df_model.collect()[0][0]
w = Window.partitionBy('id_client').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding,0).orderBy('id_sku')
df =df_model.withColumn('id_sum',
 f.sum(f.when(f.col('id_client') !=t  , 1)
 .otherwise(0))
 .over(w))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
df_model.withColumn("id_sum", row_number().over(w))
```

`row_number()` window function is used to give the sequential row number starting from 1 to the result of each window partition.